# Multidimensional Hash Elements in Perl6

Tags: hash, raku

I'm trying to assign hash variables in Perl6 as I would have in Perl.  As I'm reading through a file, I take in certain elements and assign to a hash thus:

```
%key<$barcode><$position> = $sample-id
```

where in Perl5 this would have been

```
$key{$barcode}{$position} = $sample_id
```

I can print the hash assignments after I do so, so I think that the assignment is working.

When I print this hash with

```
say %key.perl;
```

this only gives

```
{"\$barcode" => ${"\$position" => "ZZ12345"}}
```

How can I print out this multidimensional hash like Perl5's `Data::Dumper` or `DDP` https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer because `say %key.perl` doesn't seem to work for multidimensional hashes?

Comment: In what sense does `say %key.perl` not work?  `my %h = a => { b => { c => 42 } }; say %h` seems to output `{a => {b => {c => 42}}}` just fine for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<>` is the same as `{''}` in perl5 so should only be used for string keys. If you want to use the variable names go with :

`%key{$barcode}{$position} = $sample_id` this should do the trick.

You can also use the double pointy brace option which does string interpolation.

`%key<<$barcode>><<$position>> = $sample_id`

Comment: I would usually suggest not using `<<...>>` to interpolate due to it treating spaces as a separator. Consider: `perl6 -e 'my $key = "1 2 3"; my %hash = $key => 42; say %hash<<$key>>`

Comment: Yeah... but I felt I should mention them. You're probably right.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood the Perl 6 language.
(Which is understandable, and not the first time)

Below is an abridged history lesson of the feature you were trying to use.

---

In Perl 5 you didn't have to quote the key if the only thing between `{}` was a bare-word.

```perl
use v5.12;

my %hash;
$hash{fubar} = 'abc';
# $hash{'fubar'} = 'abc';

say qq'"@{[ $hash{fubar} ]}"';
# "abc"
```

That was a special-case, and one of the goals of the Perl 6 design is to have as few special-cases as possible. So the following does not work in Perl 6.

```perl6
use v6.d;

my %hash;
%hash{fubar} = 'abc';
# %hash{ fubar() } = 'abc';

say qq'"%hash{fubar}"';
# say qq'"%hash{ fubar() }"';
```

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling ./test.p6
Undeclared routine:
    fubar used at lines 4, 7
```

That error means it failed to even compile.

---

There is a feature for quote words in both Perl languages.

```perl
use v5;
my @array = qw< a b c d >;
```

```perl6
use v6;
my @array = qw< a b c d >;
```

In Perl 6 that can be shortened to

```perl6
use v6;
my @array =   < a b c d >;
```

`qw` is really short for `Q :q :w` / `Q :single :words` in Perl 6. Which is enable single-quote behaviour and enable splitting into words. (split on whitespace)
(`<>` works because the infix operator `<` is not expected there.)

To make up for the automatic bareword quoting between `{}` which was not copied over, postcircumfix `<>` was added. It combines both of the `qw` and `{}` features.

```perl6
use v6;
my %hash;

%hash{qw< foo bar baz >};
%hash{  < foo bar baz >};
%hash<    foo bar baz >;  # <---
```

---

There is an additional more advanced quotewords feature in Perl 6

```perl6
use v6;
my $a = 'a b "c d"';

say qqww<< $a e f 'g h ' '$a'>>.perl;
say     << $a e f 'g h ' '$a'>>.perl;
say     «  $a e f 'g h ' '$a' ».perl;
# All 3 are exactly equivalent
# ("a", "b", "c d", "e", "f", "g h ", "\$a")
```

`qqww` is short for `Q :qq :ww` / `Q :double :quotewords`. Which is enable double-quote behaviour and enable quote-word-splitting.

The `:double` is what enables interpolation of `$a`.
`:quotewords` splits up words on spaces, but also allows quotes to control where things get split up.
(Note that `:quotewords` happens last)

(`qqw` and `qww` also work, but there is no shortened way to write them.)

There is also a postcircumfix `<<>>` / `«»`.

```perl6
use v6;
my %hash;
my $a = 'a b "c d "';

%hash{<< $a e f 'g h ' '$a' >>};
%hash<<  $a e f 'g h ' '$a' >>;
%hash«   $a e f 'g h ' '$a'  »;

# All 3 are exactly equivalent to
%hash{'a', 'b', 'c d ', 'e', 'f', 'g h ', '$a'};
#               ^^^^^^            ^^^^^^
```

This sort-of makes it so that postfix `<>` is less of a special case.

---

The reason that a lot of examples use `%hash<fubar>` is that it is idiomatic Perl 6.
Perhaps it should be seen as a more advanced feature in the docs and have reduced usage, because you are by far not the first person to make this mistake.